# Iteration stops at zero

Tags: java, do-while

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
           System.out.println(i); 
           i++;
        } while (i==3);
    }
}

// Outputs 0
```

Why do iterations stop at zero? `while(i==3)` is a condition, which tests for equality of `i` to `3`. But then, even after incrementing the value of `i` as `i++` why the output is only `0`?

Comment: Do you mean `while (i!=3)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition would be `i!=3`. Change to `while(i!=3)`. You have mistakenly put the wrong condition in the while loop. You have said it to loop the while only when `i==3` otherwise to exit the loop. So you need to change it to

```
  do {
       System.out.println(i); 
       i++;
    } while (i!=3);
```

Hope this clarifies!

Comment: Yes! This is the answer I wanted to read... this is it... this is it...

Comment: @Anulot Which exactly what you saw in my answer :P

Comment: @MarounMaroun Reload the page :D

Comment: @Anulot Ops.. I didn't mean to switch the accepted answer.. I wanted to make sure that you *do* understand that they are exactly the same and that's what I meant.. :)) You should pick the answer that you feel helped you the most, if it's Octopus's answer, then you should accept it.

Comment: Thanks! Your music and nature is warm :) Sounds like Jazz - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKW-DV4d_Qg

Answer (score 7):

Because it'll print `i`, which is `0`, then will increment it, and won't loop since `3 != 1`:

```
do {
    System.out.println(i); //i is 0, will print 0
    i++;                   //i is now 1
} while (i==3);            //false
```

Read [The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to better understand how the do-while loop works.

I'm carefully assuming that you meant to write `while(i != 3);`, if that's the case, your program will loop and will print 0 1 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maroun! I was stuck at this question for ages :)

Comment: @Anulot You're welcome. Tip for life: **Use the debugger**, it'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: By debugger you mean the tool used to set `breakpoints` etc.

Comment: @Anulot Yes. Someday this tool will save your life ;)

Answer (score -1):

Because you increment after printing.

Comment: Yes! You are so right :) this did work... in another dimension :)